# Unity3d score increase through levels

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Wasn't sure how to title my question, but what I am trying to do is have it to where when the player advances to the next level, wether they die or win, their achieved score is added on top of the already highscore. So far my playerprefs only stores the score from the first level but doesn't add the score from every other level. How would I go about doing that? Would I need to make two seperate playerprefs and combine them? If so, how would I combine them? The following code is called in every level. Thank you in advance for any reply or help.

Heres my playerprefs code:

```
    if(score > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("brickScore")){
           PlayerPrefs.SetInt("brickScore", score);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So far my playerprefs only stores the score from the first level but
>   doesn't add the score from every other level.

So... umm... as far as I can tell you want to add the scores from the previous levels to the current score?

```
if(score > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("brickScore")){
       PlayerPrefs.SetInt("brickScore", score + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("brickScore"));
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try that and see if that gives the result I am looking for.